vimwiki: Links to files and URLs no longer work
Using Vim 9.1 32-bit on Windows 11, with Vimwiki 2.5.
I'm not sure what I might have done to cause this, but Vimwiki links to files and URLs no longer work. Examples:

https://usbank.com
[[file:time_zones.png|>>]]

Clicking on either of those, I get this message:
Error detected while processing function vimwiki#base#follow_link[75] ..
vimwiki#base#open_link[37] .. vimwiki#base#system_open_link[48] .. function
vimwiki#base#follow_link[75] .. vimwiki#base#open_link[37] ..
vimwiki#base#system_open_link[39] .. < SNR>37_win32_handler: 
line  13: 
E371: Command not found

After searching through the code, I found in ...\vimfiles\autoload\vimwiki\base.vim, line 279:
execute 'silent ! start "Title" /B ' . url

If I execute
:silent ! start "Title" /B https://usbank.com

I get "E371: Command not found", so I figured I'm on the right track. Then I tried
:silent ! cmd /c start "Title" /B https://usbank.com

and that successfully opened the link in my browser.
That's as far as I've gotten. Am I missing a file? Have I found a bug? Any help appreciated. FWIW, this problem is on my work PC, but I am pretty sure I'm using the same version of Vim and Vimwiki on my home laptop, and have no issues there.

GVim or in a terminal?

I can reproduce the problem on Windows 10. I believe it is related to the way the system() call create the process. silent !start https://usbank.com seems to work fine for me.

Use the plugin's issue tracker.

... and then create a pull request with the solution you found.

@furry_marmot Welcome to Vim! Thanks for the feedback. If the answer solves your problem don't forget the accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Don't add "Answered" in the title : use the checkmark beside the correct answer.

I suppose it is indeed a bug in vimwiki.
I would propose to replace:
execute 'silent ! start "Title" /B ' . url

By
execute 'silent' '! cmd /c start "Title" /B ' . url

